# Case Expression and dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below case expression.

```
SELECT end_dt,
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '01/01/3000' THEN '' 
 WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
  ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY')
   END ENDDATE,

CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYYMM') = '300001' THEN '' 
 WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYYMM') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM') THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
  ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYYMM')
   END ENDDATE_YYYYMM,

CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYY') = '3000' THEN ''  
 WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYY') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')
 WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYY') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') 
  ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYY')
   END ENDDATE_YYYY

   FROM  A
  LEFT  D ON A.ID = D.ID

  WHERE 1=1

    ORDER BY 1
```

OutPut:

```
End_dt                   ENDDATE       ENDDATE_YYYYMM   ENDDATE_YYYY
 12/5/2012 14:33:24       01/05/2018     201212             2012
```

Expected output:

```
  End_dt                   ENDDATE       ENDDATE_YYYYMM   ENDDATE_YYYY
 12/5/2012 14:33:24       12/5/2012     201212             2012
```

Why do I get a result of 01/05/2018 and not 12/5/2012?

Comment: You need to compare dates as `date`s, not as strings. `to_char` converts your `date`s to strings.

Comment: `FROM A LEFT D`? Does that work for you? In Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing string comparisons on dates. Stop. Do date comparisons on dates.

The *string*  `'12/5/2012'` is greater than the *string* `'01/05/2018'` because 1 is greater than 0. Oracle is performing a binary comparison.

```
SQL> select *
  2    from dual
  3   where '12/5/2012' > '01/05/2018';

D
-
X
```

Stop converting all your dates to strings and all will be well

```
SQL> select *
  2    from dual
  3   where date '2018-05-01' > date '2012-05-12';

D
-
X
```

Incidentally, the empty string `''` is equivalent to NULL in Oracle.

Your query should look like:

```
CASE WHEN A.END_DT = date '3000-01-01' then null
     WHEN A.END_DT > SYSDATE THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
     ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY')
     END ENDDATE,
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do date comparisons as strings.  It works for the other values, because you have the right format -- YYYYMMDD (or a partial piece of that).

Try this logic:

```
SELECT end_dt,
       (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = '01/01/3000' THEN '' 
             WHEN A.END_DT > SYSDATE
             THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
             ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        END) as ENDDATE,
       (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYYMM') = '300001' THEN '' 
             WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYYMM') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM')
             THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
             ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT,'YYYYMM')
        END) as ENDDATE_YYYYMM,
       (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYY') = '3000' THEN ''  
             WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYY') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
             THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
             WHEN TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYY') > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') 
             THEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') 
             ELSE TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'YYYY')
        END) as ENDDATE_YYYY
```